# IPA and APK size develop in Xamarin and native

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I had notice that the APK and IPA size of Android and iOS applications which are developed in Xamarin is a lot more than the size of the APK and IPA size developed in native.

It's because Xamarin included its own .dll file.

Is there any one who have this comparison for the APK and IPA size in native and Xamarin?

Is there a very big difference in the size for the APK and IPA developed in native and Xamarin?

Comment: Regarding iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610209/ipa-file-size-issue-in-xamarin-ios/40610515#40610515

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has a section of docs that discuss how to use the linker options to minimize the size of the final assemblies

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/